# sencha touch: Drag and delete

Tags: sencha-touch

Is there any possibility in sencha touch to delete an icon by dragging it into the trash icon,
Such as dragging it into recyclebin.

Please help me regarding this issue

Comment: yes exactly either in a tab panel or in toolbar ..............

Answer (score 0):

I've look into it but couldn't find a way to make [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/dragdrop/) work on a TabPanel.

I just managed to make my own bottom toolbar which I can drag component to and delete them.

Hope it helps